# Gnome Imageviewer 3.36.3 cannot open svg file

Tags: systemd, gimp, eog, svg

Using Ubuntu 20.04 to analyse start-up performance, I ran the following systemd command:

```
sudo systemd-analyze plot > systemd-analyze-plot.svg
```

However the default native Gnome image viewer/Eye of Gnome (eog) fails to open the svg file and outputs the error:

```
"Could not load image 
system-analyze-plot.svg
Image loading failed."
```

The eog produces no error codes, so there is no possibility of looking up a code to determine the exact reason it failed to load the image.

I recall producing the same image in Ubuntu 18.04 with an earlier version of eog and I don't recall having to install an additional app to open svg files, but then that was over 2 years ago.

UPDATE:   I thought I would just confirm if the svg file format is indeed supported by eog, if not just to remind myself and the following url confirms it is in fact supported

```
https://help.gnome.org/users/eog/stable/formats-view.html.en
```

Also I am running gimp 2.10.24.

The svg file in this case can be opened in Firefox without error but Gimp also returned the error:

```
"Could not open
 systemd-analyze-plot.svg 
 for reading: Unknown reason"
```

Perhaps the systemd-analyze plot command underwent some changes to the svg output file format, between Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 that the eog and Gimp parsers cannot interpret?

Comment: Please upload the problematic SVG file to some cloud to reproduce.

Comment: @Norbert.  Do you really need me to upload the file to the pastebin?  its easy to reproduce, since all you would need to do is run the command on Ubuntu 20.04 to produce the svg and then attempt to open it with eog or gimp.

Comment: I ran your command and Eye of Gnome (3.36.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.3) can open the SVG. Did you tried your command more than once? I try it 5 times and it always works.

Comment: I'm running ubuntu 20.04.2.  I tried several times to open with eog and gimp yesterday.   I rerun the command today and eog and gimp now open and render the svg file without error, go figure! it seems some anomaly occured, which disappeared after I restarted.  Seems like Ubuntu had a Windows moment,

Comment: If try to open the svg files I generated yesterday, both eog and gimp still cant open them and output the same error.  I'll compare both files from today and yesterday in Firefox and see what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As XML files, SVG images can be created and edited with any text editor, as well as with drawing software. Source : [Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) - Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics).

Try opening the faulty SVG with a text editor. The result of your command gave me the following text :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="2497px" height="5870px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<!-- This file is a systemd-analyze SVG file. It is best rendered in a   -->
<!-- browser such as Chrome, Chromium or Firefox. Other applications     -->
<!-- that render these files properly but much slower are ImageMagick,   -->
<!-- gimp, inkscape, etc. To display the files on your system, just      -->
<!-- point your browser to this file.                                    -->

<!-- This plot was generated by systemd-analyze version 245.4-4ubuntu3.1 -->
...
```

As you can see the [version of SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#Version_1.x) is 1.1.

You can test both your faulty SVG and the good one with the [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload+with_options). You can leave the default options and upload your file. Click Check.

If it's good, you will have the following message : `This document was successfully checked as SVG 1.1!` You can ignore the warning `No Character encoding declared at document level`.

If there is an error or more (premature end of file, etc.), this will appear : `Error found while checking this document as SVG 1.1`. Scroll down to see the errors.